# subprocess.CalledProcessError... returns non zero exit status 2

Tags: python, json, subprocess

I am making a python script to execute a shell command and then process the output. I want to execute this command:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/users/username/repos?per_page=200" | grep -o 'git@[^"]*'| awk -F "/" '{print $2}'| awk -F "." '{print $1}'
```

I am using `subprocess.check_output` method something like:

```
with open(os.devnull,'w') as devnull:
    f=subprocess.check_output(['curl', 'https://api.github.com/users/username/repos?per_page=200', '|', 'grep', '-o', 'git@[^"]*','|', 'awk' ,'-F' ,'/', '{print $2}' ,'|' ,'awk', '-F', '.' ,'{print $1}'],stderr=devnull)
    res=ujson.loads(f)
    data=res.get('items')
    print(data[0].get('login'))
```

But it gives the following Error:

```
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['curl', 'https://api.github.com/users/username/repos?per_page=200', '|', 'grep', '-o', 'git@[^"]*', '|', 'awk-F', '/', '{print $2}', '|', 'awk', '-F', '.', '{print $1}']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

I have checked the similar questions but they didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

missing space in `awk-F` command because of missing comma in `'awk' '-F'`

can you use a single string instead of an array? that might be less error prone IMHO

```
subprocess.check_output('curl https://...')
```

Comment: That comma must have been a typo, I corrected that, still got the same error.

Comment: no, `check_output` accepts either a string or a list - https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output - and what I said it exactly the thing reported by the `CalledProcessError` in your question, if you have additional question you should have asked a different question please

Comment: ..assuming that when you run the command on command line directly, it does NOT exit with the error you are trying to fix, then difference (typo) in the command is the most probable reason why you get an error here

Comment: Yes, the same command on command line runs perfectly but doesn't in python. I'll try the string as well.

Comment: I was facing an error when using awk in python. I was able to fix it by using getoutput instead of check_output

Answer (score 0):

Wich key do you want to get ?? bellow is an example using urllib2 & json

```
import urllib2 , json

data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen("https://api.github.com/users/test/repos?per_page=200"))
for repos in data:
    print repos["name"]
```

Comment: I have to process a list of users. The reason I am not using urllib2 is that because then I'd have to make multiple calls[ for each user ]. Whereas, using system calls, it does the trick in a single command.